# Como retornar a "waypoint_order" na Google Directions API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps, route

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para traçar rota utilizando o Google Maps API.

Eu tenho os pontos de origem e destino e entre esses pontos há alguns pontos de interesse. Ao traçar a rota Google me retorna a melhor rota e marcar esses pontos no mapa. Eu exibo os dados da rota em uma `div`.

Minha função que calcula a rota, a parte que retorna os dados se parece com isso:

```
directionsService.route(request, $.proxy(function(response, status){

  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    var orders = response.routes[0].waypoint_order; 
    var route = response.routes[0];
    var total_distance = 0;
    var displayRoute = $('#detail-route');

    for (i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++){

      var routeSegment = i + 1,
      from_address = route.legs[i].start_address.split(','),
      to_address = route.legs[i].end_address.split(',');
      total_distance += Math.floor(route.legs[i].distance.value / 1000);

      displayRoute.append('<b>Trecho ' + routeSegment + ': </b><br/>');
      displayRoute.append('<b>Saindo de: </b>' + from_address[0] + '<br/>');
      displayRoute.append('<b>Indo para: </b>' + to_address[0] + '<br/>');
      displayRoute.append('<b>Distância: </b>' + route.legs[i].distance.text);
    }

    displayRoute.prepend('total:' + this.format(total_distance) + ' km' + '<br/><br/>');
```

---

`function format()` é a minha função para formatar km.

O problema é que, em algumas rotas, o `waypoint_order` mostra uma ordem diferente.

**Por exemplo:**

Para uma determinada rota, os `route.legs[i]` retorna ordem:

```
waypoint 0, 1 waypoint, waypoint 3, waypoint 2
```

mas os retornos `waypoint_orderattribute [3, 0, 2, 1, 3]`.

## Pergunta

É este o comportamento esperado, ou está faltando alguma coisa?

Comment: Consegui pôr isto a funcionar? Se a resposta em baixo tiver correcta pode aceitar. Se não pode responder você para outros poderem usar no futuro...

Comment: Ainda não esta funcionando.

Answer (score 3):

Eu imagino que você tenha colocado o `optimizeWaypoints: true`, retirado da própria documentação da [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=pt-es):

> `waypoint_order` contains an array indicating the order of any waypoints in the calculated route. **This waypoints may be reordered if the request was passed `optimize:true`** within its `waypoints` parameter.

Em tradução livre:

> `waypoints_order` contém um vetor indicando a ordem de todos waypoints dentro da rota calculada. Esses waypoints **podem ser reoodernados se for passado `optimize:true`** na requisição, junto ao parâmetro `waypoints`.

Ou seja, caso você queira otimizar a rota, os pontos de caminho podem ter sua rota reorganizada e, talvez por isso, a ordem no `route.legs` esteja diferente da ordem do `waypoints`.